# Add suffix and rename while itrate over framworks

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add suffix and rename a few frame works.
for one frame work it works perfect:

```
df1 = df1.add_suffix("_1").rename(columns={"personId_1": "personId"})
```

To avoiding repetition for other data frames, I want to iterate over them for the same function.

```
scenarios =[df1,df2,df3,df4]

for scenario in scenarios:
    scenario = scenario.add_suffix("_???").rename(columns={"personId_???": "personId"})

df1.head()
```

How I can add different name as suffix?, I would prefer to add the name of the data frames as suffix.

Comment: Could you include your dataframe structure ?

Answer (score 0):

If the dataframes in scenario are in order, you can try this out :

```py
for i,scenario in enumerate(scenarios):
    scenario = scenario.add_suffix("_{}".format(i)).rename(columns={"personId_{}".format(i): "personId"})
```